# Why isn't my socket revieving the message?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to learn how to use java sockets before next semester. I wrote this program that is supposed to accept accept a message from a sender and send the message to a reciever. You specify the reciever by writing the name of the client that is connected, if the client isn't connected then the server will respond by sending the message "DISCONNECTED". But for some reason the message isn't sent to the reciever. I can still send the message to the sender though. Is this the right forum to ask for this kind of help?

This is my client class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyTestClient {

static int port = 0;
static String ip = "";
static String name = "";

public static void main(String args[] ) {

    if(args.length == 3) {

        try{
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Usage: Java MyTestClient <ip> <port> <name>");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        ip = args[0];
        name = args[2];

    } else {

        System.out.println("Usage: Java MyTestClient <ip> <port> <name>");
        System.exit(0);

    }

    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);

        new Thread(new MessageHandler(socket)).start();
        new Thread(new InputHandler(socket)).start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to: " + ip + " : " + port); 
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static class MessageHandler implements Runnable {

    Socket socket;

    public MessageHandler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String fromServer;
        try {
            while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(fromServer);
                fromServer.trim();
                if(fromServer.contains(" ")) {
                    String split[] = fromServer.split(" ", 2);
                    System.out.println(split.length == 2 ? split[1] + " Is a two part message" : "Strange message");
                } else {
                    if(fromServer.equals("NAME")) {
                        System.out.println("Server asks for name | gives given name to server");
                        out.println(name);
                    }
                    if(fromServer.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                        System.out.println("Message succesfully sent");
                    }
                    if(fromServer.equals("ERROR")) {
                        System.out.println("Something went wrong when sending the message");
                    }
                    if(fromServer.equals("OCCUPIED")) {
                        System.out.println("Name was already used. Start the program with another name");
                        socket.close();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    if(fromServer.equals("DISCONNECTED")) {
                        System.out.println("The reciever was not connected");
                    }
                    if(fromServer.equals("REGISTERED")) {
                        System.out.println("Successfully logged in to server");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public static class InputHandler implements Runnable {

    Socket socket;

    public InputHandler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String fromUser = null;

        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader kbi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            while ((fromUser = kbi.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(fromUser);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

}
```

This is my server class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyServer {

    public static int port;
    public static int maxConnections;
    public static final String NAME = "Server";
    private static Map<String, Socket> socketsMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        if(args.length == 2) {
            try{
                port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
                maxConnections = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Usage: Java Myserver <port> <maxConnections>");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: Java Myserver <port> <maxConnections>");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(port, maxConnections)).start();

    }

    public static class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {

        private ServerSocket server;
        private Socket socket = null;
        public int currentSocket = 0;
        public int port = 0;
        public int maxConnections = 0;

        public ConnectionHandler(int port, int maxConnections) {
            this.maxConnections = maxConnections;
            this.port = port;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(7777);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("Server could not connect to port: " + port);
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }

            while(currentSocket++ < maxConnections) {
                try {
                    socket = server.accept();
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    out.println("NAME");
                    String message;
                    while((message = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        if(!socketsMap.containsKey(message) || message.equals("SERVER")) {
                            out.println("REGISTERED");
                            socketsMap.put(message, socket);
                            System.out.println(message + " has logged on server");

                            new Thread(new SocketHandler(socketsMap.get(message))).start();

                        } else {
                            out.println("OCCUPIED");
                            System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress().toString() + " has tried to login with existing name " + message);
                            socket.close();
                            currentSocket--;
                        }
                        socket = null;
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Something went wrong with client connection");
                }
            }


        }

    }

    public static class SocketHandler implements Runnable {

        Socket socket = null;

        public SocketHandler(Socket socket) {

            this.socket = socket;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter respond = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                String input;
                while((input = in.readLine() ) != null) {
                    String[] info = input.split(" ", 2);

                    if(info.length != 2){
                        System.out.println("Message computed wrong");
                        respond.println("ERROR");
                        break;
                    }
                    if(info[0].equals("SERVER")) {

                        //TODO: Write a server command handler class

                    } else if ( socketsMap.containsKey(info[0]) ){

                        Socket reciever = socketsMap.get(info[0]);
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(reciever.getOutputStream());
                        respond.println("SUCCESS");
                        System.out.println(info[0] + " send the message: "+ info[1]);
                        out.println("MESSAGE" + " " + info[1]);
                        break;

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Reciever is not connected");
                        respond.println("DISCONNECTED");
                    }
                }
            }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Maybe you can run it on your computers and see what i mean?

Comment: It's not a help desk. Nobody is going to  run your code. But quite a few very experienced people are going to read it, and your question. Such as it is. But it isn't. 'Message isn't sent' is not a problem description. What happens instead? Crash? Exception? Wrong data? No data? Timeout? Connection failure?

Answer (score -1):

```
 @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(7777);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("Server could not connect to port: " + port);
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

change the code above to

```
 @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(port);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("Server could not connect to port: " + port);
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

Comment: oh for gods sake, don't give me a vote down without explaining why!!